# Routes all link to '/#/:path'

Tags: ember.js

I am trying out ember.js with rails, and have a question about routing. Is a `#` sign supposed to be in every one of my routes?

I have a really simple app with only one route:

```
App.Router.map () ->
  @resource "blogs"
```

When I go to my index path, my index template is rendered as expected, it has a link to the blogs route `{{#link-to 'blogs'}}Blogs{{/link-to}}` that has a corresponding template located as `templates/blogs`. When clicking on this link, my app redirects to `host.com/#/blogs`. Is this the expected behavior with the `#` being placed in the path? Navigating to `/blogs` simply renders the index template and not `templates/blogs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, Ember, like many frameworks, takes advantage of using the hash sign for its routing.  You can disable it and use location as your history, but that will limit the browsers you support (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/).

You'll recognize the hash sign is generally used as a way of bookmarking a spot on the page, and when you click a link with the hash the base url never changes.  This allows the page to change the url, but not have to refresh the entire page.